# Attempting DirectX Sphere in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

Below is my code so far. I know I have several unneeded methods. I just need one that works. The ppMesh->DrawSubset is throwing an exception 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000. I don't know how to fix this. i just want to be able to render a sphere in DirectX.

If it is possible I also need to have it spinning.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#include <xnamath.h>
#include "resource.h"
#include <d3dx10.h>
#include <vector>
#include <d3dx9.h>


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Structures
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct SimpleVertex
{
    XMFLOAT3 Pos;
    XMFLOAT4 Color;
};


struct ConstantBuffer
{
    XMMATRIX mWorld;
    XMMATRIX mView;
    XMMATRIX mProjection;
};


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Global Variables
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HINSTANCE               g_hInst = NULL;
HWND                    g_hWnd = NULL;
D3D_DRIVER_TYPE         g_driverType = D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_NULL;
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL       g_featureLevel = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0;
ID3D11Device*           g_pd3dDevice = NULL;
ID3D11DeviceContext*    g_pImmediateContext = NULL;
IDXGISwapChain*         g_pSwapChain = NULL;
ID3D11RenderTargetView* g_pRenderTargetView = NULL;
ID3D11VertexShader*     g_pVertexShader = NULL;
ID3D11PixelShader*      g_pPixelShader = NULL;
ID3D11InputLayout*      g_pVertexLayout = NULL;
ID3D11Buffer*           g_pVertexBuffer = NULL;
ID3D11Buffer*           g_pIndexBuffer = NULL;
ID3D11Buffer*           g_pConstantBuffer = NULL; 
XMMATRIX                g_World;
XMMATRIX                g_View;
XMMATRIX                g_Projection;
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9       pDevice9;
LPD3DXMESH              ppMesh;
LPD3DXBUFFER*           ppAdjacency;


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Forward declarations
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT InitWindow( HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow );
HRESULT InitDevice();
void CleanupDevice();
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc( HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM );
void Update();
void Render();
void singleCollision();
void applyFriction();
void createSphere(_In_ ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext, float diameter, size_t tessellation, bool rhcoords, bool invertn);

double angle = 45, velY = 0, velX = 0, degree = 0, z = 0, mass = 10, initVel = 350, windRes = .02, time = 0;
float wallTopLX = 5.0f, wallTopLY = 0.0f, wallTopLZ = 2.3f;
float wallBotRX = 5.0f, wallBotRY = -2.0f, wallBotRZ = 2.0f;
float sphereX = 1.0f, sphereY = 1.0f, sphereZ = 1.0f;
float groundY = -2.0f;
float tarTopLX = 5.0f, tarTopLY = 0.0f, tarTopLZ = 2.3f;
float tarBotRX = 5.0f, tarBotRY = -2.0f, tarBotRZ = 2.0f;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Entry point to the program. Initializes everything and goes into a message processing 
// loop. Idle time is used to render the scene.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int WINAPI wWinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow )
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( hPrevInstance );
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( lpCmdLine );

    if( FAILED( InitWindow( hInstance, nCmdShow ) ) )
        return 0;

    if( FAILED( InitDevice() ) )
    {
        CleanupDevice();
        return 0;
    }

    // Main message loop
    MSG msg = {0};
    while( WM_QUIT != msg.message )
    {
        if( PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) )
        {
            TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessage( &msg );
        }
        else
        {
            Update();
            Render();
        }
    }

    CleanupDevice();

    return ( int )msg.wParam;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Register class and create window
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT InitWindow( HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow )
{
    // Register class
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof( WNDCLASSEX );
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon( hInstance, ( LPCTSTR )IDI_TUTORIAL1 );
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW );
    wcex.hbrBackground = ( HBRUSH )( COLOR_WINDOW + 1 );
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = L"TutorialWindowClass";
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon( wcex.hInstance, ( LPCTSTR )IDI_TUTORIAL1 );
    if( !RegisterClassEx( &wcex ) )
        return E_FAIL;

    // Create window
    g_hInst = hInstance;
    RECT rc = { 0, 0, 640, 480 };
    AdjustWindowRect( &rc, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE );
    g_hWnd = CreateWindow( L"TutorialWindowClass", L"Direct3D 11 Tutorial 4: 3D Spaces", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                           CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, NULL, NULL, hInstance,
                           NULL );
    if( !g_hWnd )
        return E_FAIL;

    ShowWindow( g_hWnd, nCmdShow );

    return S_OK;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Helper for compiling shaders with D3DX11
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT CompileShaderFromFile( WCHAR* szFileName, LPCSTR szEntryPoint, LPCSTR szShaderModel, ID3DBlob** ppBlobOut )
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    DWORD dwShaderFlags = D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_STRICTNESS;
#if defined( DEBUG ) || defined( _DEBUG )
    // Set the D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG flag to embed debug information in the shaders.
    // Setting this flag improves the shader debugging experience, but still allows 
    // the shaders to be optimized and to run exactly the way they will run in 
    // the release configuration of this program.
    dwShaderFlags |= D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG;
#endif

    ID3DBlob* pErrorBlob;
    hr = D3DX11CompileFromFile( szFileName, NULL, NULL, szEntryPoint, szShaderModel, 
        dwShaderFlags, 0, NULL, ppBlobOut, &pErrorBlob, NULL );
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        if( pErrorBlob != NULL )
            OutputDebugStringA( (char*)pErrorBlob->GetBufferPointer() );
        if( pErrorBlob ) pErrorBlob->Release();
        return hr;
    }
    if( pErrorBlob ) pErrorBlob->Release();

    return S_OK;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Create Direct3D device and swap chain
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT InitDevice()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect( g_hWnd, &rc );
    UINT width = rc.right - rc.left;
    UINT height = rc.bottom - rc.top;

    UINT createDeviceFlags = 0;
#ifdef _DEBUG
    createDeviceFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif

    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE driverTypes[] =
    {
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE,
    };
    UINT numDriverTypes = ARRAYSIZE( driverTypes );

    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] =
    {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
    };
    UINT numFeatureLevels = ARRAYSIZE( featureLevels );

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sd;
    ZeroMemory( &sd, sizeof( sd ) );
    sd.BufferCount = 1;
    sd.BufferDesc.Width = width;
    sd.BufferDesc.Height = height;
    sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    sd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    sd.OutputWindow = g_hWnd;
    sd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    sd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    sd.Windowed = TRUE;

    for( UINT driverTypeIndex = 0; driverTypeIndex < numDriverTypes; driverTypeIndex++ )
    {
        g_driverType = driverTypes[driverTypeIndex];
        hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain( NULL, g_driverType, NULL, createDeviceFlags, featureLevels, numFeatureLevels,
                                            D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &sd, &g_pSwapChain, &g_pd3dDevice, &g_featureLevel, &g_pImmediateContext );
        if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
            break;
    }
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;

    // Create a render target view
    ID3D11Texture2D* pBackBuffer = NULL;
    hr = g_pSwapChain->GetBuffer( 0, __uuidof( ID3D11Texture2D ), ( LPVOID* )&pBackBuffer );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;

    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateRenderTargetView( pBackBuffer, NULL, &g_pRenderTargetView );
    pBackBuffer->Release();
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;

    g_pImmediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets( 1, &g_pRenderTargetView, NULL );

    // Setup the viewport
    D3D11_VIEWPORT vp;
    vp.Width = (FLOAT)width;
    vp.Height = (FLOAT)height;
    vp.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    vp.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    vp.TopLeftX = 0;
    vp.TopLeftY = 0;
    g_pImmediateContext->RSSetViewports( 1, &vp );

    // Compile the vertex shader
    ID3DBlob* pVSBlob = NULL;
    hr = CompileShaderFromFile( L"Tutorial04.fx", "VS", "vs_4_0", &pVSBlob );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
    {
        MessageBox( NULL,
                    L"The FX file cannot be compiled.  Please run this executable from the directory that contains the FX file.", L"Error", MB_OK );
        return hr;
    }

    // Create the vertex shader
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateVertexShader( pVSBlob->GetBufferPointer(), pVSBlob->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &g_pVertexShader );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
    {   
        pVSBlob->Release();
        return hr;
    }

    // Define the input layout
    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] =
    {
        { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
        { "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    };
    UINT numElements = ARRAYSIZE( layout );

    // Create the input layout
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateInputLayout( layout, numElements, pVSBlob->GetBufferPointer(),
                                          pVSBlob->GetBufferSize(), &g_pVertexLayout );
    pVSBlob->Release();
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;

    // Set the input layout
    g_pImmediateContext->IASetInputLayout( g_pVertexLayout );

    // Compile the pixel shader
    ID3DBlob* pPSBlob = NULL;
    hr = CompileShaderFromFile( L"Tutorial04.fx", "PS", "ps_4_0", &pPSBlob );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
    {
        MessageBox( NULL,
                    L"The FX file cannot be compiled.  Please run this executable from the directory that contains the FX file.", L"Error", MB_OK );
        return hr;
    }

    // Create the pixel shader
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreatePixelShader( pPSBlob->GetBufferPointer(), pPSBlob->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &g_pPixelShader );
    pPSBlob->Release();
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;
    // Create vertex buffer
    SimpleVertex wallVertices[] =
    {
        { XMFLOAT3(wallTopLX, wallTopLY, wallTopLZ), XMFLOAT4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) },
        { XMFLOAT3( 5.0f, 0.0f, 2.3f ), XMFLOAT4( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ) },
        { XMFLOAT3( 5.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f ), XMFLOAT4( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ) },
        { XMFLOAT3( -5.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f ), XMFLOAT4( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ) },
        { XMFLOAT3( -5.0f, -2.0f, 2.3f ), XMFLOAT4( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ) },
        { XMFLOAT3( 5.0f, -2.0f, 2.3f ), XMFLOAT4( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ) },
        { XMFLOAT3(wallBotRX, wallBotRY, wallBotRZ), XMFLOAT4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f) },
        { XMFLOAT3( -5.0f, -2.0f, 2.0f ), XMFLOAT4( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ) },
    };
    SimpleVertex tarVertices[] =
    {
        { XMFLOAT3(tarTopLX, tarTopLY, tarTopLZ), XMFLOAT4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) },
        { XMFLOAT3(5.0f, 0.0f, 2.3f), XMFLOAT4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) },
        { XMFLOAT3(5.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f), XMFLOAT4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f) },
        { XMFLOAT3(-5.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f), XMFLOAT4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) },
        { XMFLOAT3(-5.0f, -2.0f, 2.3f), XMFLOAT4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) },
        { XMFLOAT3(5.0f, -2.0f, 2.3f), XMFLOAT4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) },
        { XMFLOAT3(tarBotRX, tarBotRY, tarBotRZ), XMFLOAT4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f) },
        { XMFLOAT3(-5.0f, -2.0f, 2.0f), XMFLOAT4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) },
    };



    float t = (1.0 + sqrt(5.0) / 2);
    SimpleVertex sphereVertices[] =
    {
        XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, t, 2.3f), XMFLOAT4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),//0
        XMFLOAT3(1.0f, t, 2.3f), XMFLOAT4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),//1
        XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -t, 2.3f), XMFLOAT4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),//2
        XMFLOAT3(1.0f, -t, 2.3f), XMFLOAT4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),//3

        XMFLOAT3(0.0f, -1.0f, t), XMFLOAT4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),//4
        XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 1.0f, t), XMFLOAT4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),//5
        XMFLOAT3(0.0f, -1.0f, -t), XMFLOAT4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),//6
        XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 1.0f, -t), XMFLOAT4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),//7

        XMFLOAT3(t, 0.0f, 2.3f), XMFLOAT4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),//8
        XMFLOAT3(t, 0.0f, 2.3f), XMFLOAT4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),//9
        XMFLOAT3(-t, 0.0f, 2.3f), XMFLOAT4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),//10
        XMFLOAT3(-t, 0.0f, 2.3f), XMFLOAT4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),//11
    };



    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
    ZeroMemory( &bd, sizeof(bd) );
    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof( SimpleVertex ) * 8;
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
    ZeroMemory( &InitData, sizeof(InitData) );
    InitData.pSysMem = sphereVertices;
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer( &bd, &InitData, &g_pVertexBuffer );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;

    // Set vertex buffer
    UINT stride = sizeof( SimpleVertex );
    UINT offset = 0;
    g_pImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers( 0, 1, &g_pVertexBuffer, &stride, &offset );

    // Create index buffer
    WORD indices[] =
    {
        3,1,0,
        2,1,3,

        0,5,4,
        1,5,0,

        3,4,7,
        0,4,3,

        1,6,5,
        2,6,1,

        2,7,6,
        3,7,2,

        6,4,5,
        7,4,6,
    };
    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof( WORD ) * 36;        // 36 vertices needed for 12 triangles in a triangle list
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    InitData.pSysMem = indices;
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer( &bd, &InitData, &g_pIndexBuffer );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;

    // Set index buffer
    g_pImmediateContext->IASetIndexBuffer( g_pIndexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0 );

    // Set primitive topology
    g_pImmediateContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology( D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST );

    // Create the constant buffer
    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(ConstantBuffer);
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer( &bd, NULL, &g_pConstantBuffer );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;

    // Initialize the world matrix
    g_World = XMMatrixIdentity();

    // Initialize the view matrix
    XMVECTOR Eye = XMVectorSet( 0.0f, 1.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f );
    XMVECTOR At = XMVectorSet( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    XMVECTOR Up = XMVectorSet( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    g_View = XMMatrixLookAtLH( Eye, At, Up );

    // Initialize the projection matrix
    g_Projection = XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH( XM_PIDIV2, width / (FLOAT)height, 0.01f, 100.0f );

    return S_OK;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Clean up the objects we've created
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void CleanupDevice()
{
    if( g_pImmediateContext ) g_pImmediateContext->ClearState();

    if( g_pConstantBuffer ) g_pConstantBuffer->Release();
    if( g_pVertexBuffer ) g_pVertexBuffer->Release();
    if( g_pIndexBuffer ) g_pIndexBuffer->Release();
    if( g_pVertexLayout ) g_pVertexLayout->Release();
    if( g_pVertexShader ) g_pVertexShader->Release();
    if( g_pPixelShader ) g_pPixelShader->Release();
    if( g_pRenderTargetView ) g_pRenderTargetView->Release();
    if( g_pSwapChain ) g_pSwapChain->Release();
    if( g_pImmediateContext ) g_pImmediateContext->Release();
    if( g_pd3dDevice ) g_pd3dDevice->Release();
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Called every time the application receives a message
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch( message )
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint( hWnd, &ps );
            EndPaint( hWnd, &ps );
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage( 0 );
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc( hWnd, message, wParam, lParam );
    }

    return 0;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Update
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Update()
{
    if (GetAsyncKeyState('W'))//up
    {
        angle++;//angle = barrel up to down
    }
    if (GetAsyncKeyState('A'))//left
    {
        z++;//z = barrel left to right
    }
    if (GetAsyncKeyState('S'))//down
    {
        angle--;
    }
    if (GetAsyncKeyState('D'))//right
    {
        z++;
    }
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE))//shoot
    {
        singleCollision();
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Render a frame
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Render()
{
    D3DXCreateSphere(pDevice9, 2.0f, 10, 10, &ppMesh, ppAdjacency);
    ppMesh->DrawSubset(0);
    // Update our time
    static float t = 0.0f;
    if( g_driverType == D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE )
    {
        t += ( float )XM_PI * 0.0125f;
    }
    else
    {
        static DWORD dwTimeStart = 0;
        DWORD dwTimeCur = GetTickCount();
        if( dwTimeStart == 0 )
            dwTimeStart = dwTimeCur;
        t = ( dwTimeCur - dwTimeStart ) / 1000.0f;
    }

    //
    // Animate the cube
    //
    //g_World = XMMatrixRotationY( t );

    //
    // Clear the back buffer
    //
    float ClearColor[4] = { 0.0f, 0.125f, 0.3f, 1.0f }; // red,green,blue,alpha
    g_pImmediateContext->ClearRenderTargetView( g_pRenderTargetView, ClearColor );

    //
    // Update variables
    //
    ConstantBuffer cb;
    cb.mWorld = XMMatrixTranspose( g_World );
    cb.mView = XMMatrixTranspose( g_View );
    cb.mProjection = XMMatrixTranspose( g_Projection );
    g_pImmediateContext->UpdateSubresource( g_pConstantBuffer, 0, NULL, &cb, 0, 0 );

    //
    // Renders a triangle
    //
    g_pImmediateContext->VSSetShader( g_pVertexShader, NULL, 0 );
    g_pImmediateContext->VSSetConstantBuffers( 0, 1, &g_pConstantBuffer );
    g_pImmediateContext->PSSetShader( g_pPixelShader, NULL, 0 );
    g_pImmediateContext->DrawIndexed( 36, 0, 0 );        // 36 vertices needed for 12 triangles in a triangle list

    //
    // Present our back buffer to our front buffer
    //
    g_pSwapChain->Present( 0, 0 );
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Define Collisions
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void singleCollision()
{
    degree = angle*(3.1415926 / 180);//change radian angle into degree for velocity calc
    velY = initVel * sin(degree);//determine y axis velocity
    velX = initVel * cos(degree);//determine x axis velocity
    bool hit = false;
    while (!hit)
    {
        applyFriction();
        sphereZ += velX / 10;
        sphereY += velY / 10;
        velY -= 9.81;
        if (sphereY <= groundY){}//collision with ground
        if (sphereX >= wallTopLX && sphereX <= wallBotRX)//sphere is in correct x coords for collision with wall
            if (sphereY >= wallTopLY && sphereY <= wallBotRY)//sphere is in correct y coords for collision with wall
                if (sphereZ >= wallTopLZ && sphereZ <= wallBotRZ)//sphere is in correct y coords for collision with wall
                {
                    //collision with wall
                }
        if (sphereX >= tarTopLX && sphereX <= tarBotRX)//sphere is in correct x coords for collision with target
            if (sphereY >= tarTopLY && sphereY <= tarBotRY)//sphere is in correct y coords for collision with target
                if (sphereZ >= tarTopLZ && sphereZ <= tarBotRZ)//sphere is in correct y coords for collision with target
                {
                    //collision with target
                }
    }
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Apply Friction
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void applyFriction(){
    velX -= windRes*velX;//drag equation with wind resistance
    time += 1;
}

void createSphere(_In_ ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext, float diameter, size_t tessellation, bool rhcoords, bool invertn)
{
}
```

Comment: First, posting an entire file here is just gonna make debugging/helping you all the more difficult. We didn't write this and we have to read through the code to see what is going on and where the issue is. Only include the part that you need help with. Second, dont write stuff like 'i need to have it spinning'. This is a learning community and not write-my-code-for-me type of place so please don't ask people to write code for you. They will write code to fix what you have but not for what you don't. Otherwise, happy coding!

Comment: Does your call to D3DXCreateSphere succeed? Try wrapping it in a test, e.g. `if (FAILED(D3DXCreateSphere(...))) { return NULL; }` and stepping through.

Comment: This code is kind of a mess of Direct3D 11, Direct3D 10, and Direct3D 9 stuff. Keep in mind that D3DX9. D3DX10, D3DX11, and the entire DirectX SDK is [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx). You should take a look at the _DirectX Tool Kit_ tutorials, particularly the one on drawing [3D shapes like a sphere](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/3D-shapes).